# What is the best approach to track a huge object in Vuforia with Unity 3D? (size of +40 meters)

Tags: unity-game-engine, ipad, vuforia, object-tracking

I am looking for a solution/ best practice on how I should solve the issue of tracking an enormous object. The object that I would like to track is over 40 meters. Is it even possible with Vuforia? (I would like to use Unity 3D with Vuforia, on an iPad Pro)

I've read some articles on Vuforia Area Targets and Model Targets. As far as I know, Model Targets works for models in a scale of a few meters, whereas Area Targets has a totally different use-case.

Comment: Track .. from how far away? ;) Is the object moving or static? Speaks something against only anchoring once vía e.g. QR code marker and then let your device's spacial tracking handle the rest? From my experience the best practice would be to not use Vuforia ^^ but that's just my biased opinion ^^

Comment: What is the object? I'm assuming it's outside? What are the lighting conditions? What do you need to track it for? Is there content you wish to augment it with? What does that look like? There are a ton of potential possible variables involved in choosing an approach to this problem.

Comment: So, I have done similar things before (tracking/pseudo-tracking large objects). But as others have said, I could do with a lot more info! I say pseudo-tracking because there are ways you can track smaller portions of the large object, or another smaller object with a known size and position, using images or object tracking. You can then anchor the session to those, and position the larger content relative to the known objects/trackable. Does that make sense?

Comment: Computer vision-wise a very large object from a large distance works similarly to a small object at a short distance. Even Model Targets might be ok. The right solution depends a lot on the use case. Do you just want to track in one or a few localized regions? Then creating a few separate targets might work. Do you want a well aligned experience as you move around a large space while being relative close to the target? Then relying just on spacial tracking might not be enough, depending on the level of alignment you need. Hard to recommend a solution without more information.